# Handle canceling of Azure DevOps stage in unit test (MSTest)

Tags: c#, azure-devops, mstest

I would like to ask if there is some way to handle cancelling of stage in Azure DevOps in the unit test.

I have a release pipeline with stages and inside these stages I am executing unit tests using MSTest (dotnet vstest). When tests are running and someone cancel the stage, I would like to have a possibility to react on that in the unit test. For example to be able to log this event to the log file.

From the agent logs I can see that this exception is being thrown when I cancel the stage, but seems it is being thrown after the test finishes. I am not able to catch the OperationCancelException.

```
2021-10-15T12:08:30.2970557Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2021-10-15T12:08:30.2987473Z ##[debug]System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
```

I have tried something like this, but with no success, I am not able to catch it:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class SimpleTest : BaseTest
    {
        public void SimpleTestMethod()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start of the test.");
                // Do the testing

            }
            catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Operation was cancelled!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is some info, that canceling the stage fires SIGINT signal to child processes, but I am not sure how the implementation in unit test should look like so I am able to handle it.

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/design/jobcancellation.md

If anyone has experience with handling the cancel event during release pipeline process I would appreciate if you can share some examples or so, thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I was hoping for some hint, example or explanation :) It is quite complex, I simplified it as much as possible to the example above.